TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'
import time

def timmer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time
        print(f"{func.__name__} ran in {end_time - start_time} seconds")
        return result
    return wrapper

@timmer
def example_function(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    
example_function(2)

I'm trying to calculate the time but facing this error
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'float'.

start_time = time.time()
:
end_time = time.time

That second statement sets end_time to the function object rather than to the result of the function call. That's why it's complaining about subtracting a float from a function when you attempt to calculate end_time - start_time.
You need () at the end so that it calls the function and uses the return value, the same as when you set start_time:
end_time = time.time()


import time

def timmer(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        start_time = time.time()
        result = func(*args, **kwargs)
        end_time = time.time()
        print(f"{func.__name__} ran in {end_time - start_time} seconds")
        return result
    return wrapper

@timmer
def example_function(n):
    time.sleep(n)
    
example_function(2)



end_time = time.time()


Thank you for posting this answer. While this code may answer the question, might you please [edit] your post to add an explanation as to why/how it works? This can help future readers understand and apply your answer. You are also more likely to get positive feedback (upvotes) when you include an explanation.  (In particular, it's very hard to see that you changed end_time = time.time to end_time = time.time().)
